# How to put an element at right of width:100% element?

Tags: css, positioning

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Evatp/1/

HTML:

`<input type="text" />`

`<a href=""></a>`

CSS:

`input { width:100%; margin-right:-16px; float:left; }`

`a { display: inline-block; width:16px; height:16px; float:right; background:red; }`

Why the negative margin doesn't work? I need the input to be 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but you can do the following:

```
input { width:calc(100% - 24px); margin-right:-16px; float:left; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Evatp/2/

Also make sure to provide for different browsers:

```
width: -moz-calc(100% - 24px);
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 24px);
width: -o-calc(100% - 24px);
width: calc(100% - 24px);
```

and check here for browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

For a safer approach, you can put your input in a container div with a margin on the right http://jsfiddle.net/Evatp/4/ :

```
<div id = "container">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<a href=""></a>

#container {
margin-right: 24px;
border: 1px solid blue;
}

input { 
    width: 100%;
    float:left; 
}

a { 
    display: inline-block; 
    width:16px; 
    height:16px; 
    float:right; 
    background:red; 
}
```

Comment: Make sure to take a look at [calc browser support](http://caniuse.com/calc) before using it

Comment: `calc` really isn't the way to go with this...faulty browser support and unnecessary. The issue was that the OP didn't calculate the appropriate amount of negative margins.